# Set or modify specific attribute value of a authenticated user in Active Directory

Tags: node.js, active-directory

After successful authentication against AD, how can we modify a specific attribute value for that user in nodejs.

I am using the `extensionName` attribute for a different purpose.

I can directly set that from Active Directory console. But I have to do it programmatically in nodejs

Comment: Check this link and specially the topic **Custom Entry Parsing**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2 to get an idea on how to modify the attribute(s).

Comment: No I didnt help. Its all "reads" no "writes".

Comment: It has write if you carefully follow what I said - assign value to the attribute as per Custom Entry Parsing section:  `entry.extensionAttributeN= yourValue;` after getting the DirectoryEntry `entry` for the AD Server.

Comment: I see that. The read values can be modified according to our needs. But it doesn't not set and persist that back on AD.I mean there is no "save" or "update" the new attribute value back on AD.

Comment: Again, not sure for node.js, but, in C#, it is as simple as `entry.CommitChanges()`. Please try to explore if such function exists in node.